# JOLT Transformation split objects from JSON with common values

Tags: json, jolt

I have an array of objects and I want to split each key from the object into a separate array in JSON.

Input JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "Company": "Tesla",
    "Age": 30.2
  },
  {
    "Company": "Facebook",
    "Age": 40.5
  },
  {
    "Company": "Amazon",
    "Age": 60
  }
]
```

Expected Output

```json
[
  {
    "value": "Tesla",
    "variable": "Company",
    "model": "device"
  },
  {
    "value": "Facebook",
    "variable": "Company",
    "model": "device"
  },
  {
    "value": "Amazon",
    "variable": "Company",
    "model": "device"
  },
  {
    "value": 30.2,
    "variable": "Age",
    "model": "device"
  },
  {
    "value": 40.5,
    "variable": "Age",
    "model": "device"
  },
  {
    "value": 60,
    "variable": "Age",
    "model": "device"
  }
]
```

Here the value of the Model is fixed. I have tried with some jolt spec. It's not working.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **shift** transformation spec such as

```json
[
  {
    // distinguish the attributes by indexes
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "@": "&1[&2].value", // @ represents values of the keys inherited from one upper level, &1 represents keys "Company" or "Age", [&2] represents going tree two levels up to grab the outermost indexes in an array fashion
          "$": "&1[&2].variable", // $ represents values of the keys inherited from one upper level
          "#device": "&1[&2].model"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // get rid of object/array labels
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

**Edit** : If the input was

```json
[
  {
    "Company": "Tesla",
    "Age": 30.2,
    "Time": "27/10/1992"
  },
  {
    "Company": "Facebook",
    "Age": 40.5,
    "Time": "27/10/1982"
  }
]
```

as mentioned in the comment, then you could convert the spec to

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Company|Age": {
          "@": "&1[&2].value",
          "$": "&1[&2].variable",
          "@(1,Time)": "&1[&2].DateofBirth",
          "#device": "&1[&2].model"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

in order to get the following desired output :

```json
[
  {
    "value": "Tesla",
    "variable": "Company",
    "DateofBirth": "27/10/1992",
    "model": "device"
  },
  {
    "value": "Facebook",
    "variable": "Company",
    "DateofBirth": "27/10/1982",
    "model": "device"
  },
  {
    "value": 30.2,
    "variable": "Age",
    "DateofBirth": "27/10/1992",
    "model": "device"
  },
  {
    "value": 40.5,
    "variable": "Age",
    "DateofBirth": "27/10/1982",
    "model": "device"
  }
]
```

Comment: If i want to keep extra one properties every array how to do this.Like Input json
[ { "Company": "Tesla", "Age": 30.2, "Time" : "27/10/1992" }, { "Company": "Facebook", "Age": 40.5, "Time" : "27/10/1982" } ]
Expected output Json 
[ { "value": "Tesla", "variable": "Company", "DateofBirth" :"27/10/1992", "model": "device" }, { "value": "Facebook", "variable": "Company", "DateofBirth" : "27/10/1982", "model": "device" }, { "value": 30.2, "variable": "Age", "DateofBirth" :"27/10/1992", "model": "device" }, { "value": 40.5, "variable": "Age", "DateofBirth" : "27/10/1982", "model": "device" } ]

Comment: I've just edited, take care @SumitManna .